# How to download MODIS NBAR（MCD43B4）product?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis

*Description:*
The MODIS nadir bidirectional reflectance distribution function adjusted reflectance (NBAR) product (MCD43B4), 1 km spatial resolution and a composited 16 day temporal resolution.
*Question:*
I want to download this product for analysis, but can not find it in NASA  (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/). However, I can find the data description in MODIS (https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/mod43.php). So, how can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly it seems this product did not survive the transition from Version 5 to Version 6 processing and production was terminated after March 14, 2017.

According to [the slides](https://earth.esa.int/documents/700255/2126406/ESALPVE_MODIS_Viirs_Albedo_Frascati_Jan2014.pdf) presented by Crystal Shaaf at the ESA LPVE 2014 [Land Product Validation and Evaluation Workshop](https://earth.esa.int/web/sppa/meetings-workshops/lpve/programme) this product was considered redundant and was discontinued in Collection 6 in favor of MCD43A 500m products. (*Zhuosen Wang et al. Evaluation and Inter-comparison of MODIS and VIIRS Measures of Daily Albedo - ESA LPVE 2014, January 28-30, 2014*)

```
Initially 1km, increased to 500m gridded retrievals (MCD43A)
 - MCD43B became lower quality average of underlying 500m 
 - MCD43B dropped in V006
```

Collection 5 MCD43B4 data from  February 18, 2000 up to March 14, 2017 can be downloaded from the [Chiba University archive](ftp://modis.cr.chiba-u.ac.jp/ichii/DATA/MODIS/ORG/e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD43B4.005/).

Collection 6 500m MCD43A4 is available via HTTPS from [USGS LP DAAC](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD43A4.006/).

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. The question nagged me for days. So, if I want to get monthly, 1km NBAR dataset based on 500m, daily MCD43A4 product. should I calculate maximum or average of daily product, which is better ?

Comment: @changkx I need to check that, but if my memory serves me well, MCD43 16 day span chooses the "best" of up to 16 daily BRDF values according to some definition of "best". Aggregate functions in multispectral do not usually make sense. Consider e.g. a time span that covers the transition from snow to bare soil, neither average, nor maximum would be consistent across the channels. The ATBD should have all the answers.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion provides beneficial reference and revelation for me. I will check the ATBD for detailed information.